# Optimizing website and fix issues for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have this website I am making:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgdm8/

```css
.content {          
  background: url('images/ROME-960x700pix-width-BG_03.jpg') no-repeat center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

How do I make it into a mobile ready website?

Comment: i think you need get some idea about responsive website?

Comment: whenever you view it on mobile phones or tablets it becomes smaller

Answer (score 0):

Check css [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) it can help you to develop universal design for different screen resolutions (for mobile too).
Also you can use browser detection and redirect all mobile users to you site subdomain like m.your_site.com where mobile version of your site will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try learning media queries. Here are some slides that can guide you:

http://www.slideshare.net/zomigi/building-responsive-layouts-15508821

Here is also a good tutorial that can get you started with a template too:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dreamweaver` also to covert there is an option to do this but not that robust but you can try you never know it may work in my case it didn't so I tried media queries and JQuery.

For jquery implementation refer to this site

http://devproconnections.com/jquery/jquery-mobile-tutorial-how-convert-existing-website-mobile-website
Great website must refer even if u dont want to.
OR

If you want to do this by hand u have to use media queries.

example

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    
.content {           
   background: url('images/ROME-960x700pix-width-BG_03.jpg') no-repeat center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
   max-width: 80%;
   text-align: center;
}
}
```

For whole tutorial refer: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

You must refer to the whole page of the above link before getting started. enjoy

Answer (score 0):

To make your website mobile-ready:

Add this meta tag in your HTML :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Use CSS media queries to adjust styles for smaller screens:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* tablets and desktop */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* phones */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* portrait phones */
}
```

These changes will optimize your website for mobile devices.